# How to append a piece of XML tag inside existing XML file

Tags: java, xml, dom

I just want to append the below piece of XML tags into existing XML. But When I tried to perform that It throws below error message.

> [Fatal Error] :9:16: The markup in the document following the root
>   element must be well-formed. Exception in thread "main"
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 16; The
>   markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

The below piece trying to append into existing XML:

```
<test-method duration-ms="4"  finished-at="2018-08-16T21:46:55Z"  is-config="true"  test-instance-name="DummyTestcase" >
    <reporter-output>
        <line>
        </line>
    </reporter-output>
</test-method>
```

**Existing XML file:**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <testng-results skipped="0" failed="0" total="10" passed="10">
        <test-method status="FAIL" is-config="true" duration-ms="4"
            started-at="2018-08-16T21:43:38Z" finished-at="2018-08-16T21:43:38Z">
            <params>
                <param index="0">
                    <value>               
          <![CDATA[org.testng.TestRunner@31c2affc]]>
                    </value>
                </param>
            </params>
            <reporter-output>
            </reporter-output>
        </test-method> <!-- setParameter -->


        <test-method status="FAIL" is-config="true" duration-ms="5"
            started-at="2018-08-16T21:44:55Z" finished-at="2018-08-16T21:44:55Z">
            <reporter-output>
                <line>             
         <![CDATA[runSettlement Value Set :false]]>
                </line>
            </reporter-output>
        </test-method> <!-- setSettlementFlag -->

    </testng-results>
```

**Code:**

```
        docBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(content));
        doc = docBuilder.parse(is);
        NodeList rootElement = doc.getElementsByTagName("test-method");
        Element element=(Element)rootElement.item(0);

        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

        for(String str:dataObj)
        {
            sb.append(str);
        }

        String getContent=sb.toString();

        System.out.println(getContent);

        docBuilder1 = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        is1 = new InputSource();
        is1.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(getContent));
        doc1 = docBuilder1.parse(is1);

        Node copiedNode = (Node) doc1.importNode(element, true);

        doc1.getDocumentElement().appendChild(copiedNode);
```

**Expected Output:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <testng-results skipped="0" failed="0" total="10" passed="10">
        <test-method status="FAIL" is-config="true" duration-ms="4"
            started-at="2018-08-16T21:43:38Z" finished-at="2018-08-16T21:43:38Z">
            <params>
                <param index="0">
                    <value>              
          <![CDATA[org.testng.TestRunner@31c2affc]]>
                    </value>
                </param>
            </params>
            <reporter-output>
            </reporter-output>
        </test-method> <!-- setParameter -->
        <test-method status="FAIL" is-config="true" duration-ms="5"
            started-at="2018-08-16T21:44:55Z" finished-at="2018-08-16T21:44:55Z">
            <reporter-output>
                <line>                   
        <![CDATA[runSettlement Value Set :false]]>
                </line>
            </reporter-output>
        </test-method> <!-- setSettlementFlag -->

<!--The below lines are appended -->
         </test-method><test-method duration-ms="4"  finished-at="2018-08-16T21:46:55Z"  is-config="true"  test-instance-name="DummyTestcase" >
            <reporter-output>
                <line>
                </line>
            </reporter-output>
    </test-method>

</testng-results>
```

The above piece of XML tag should be appended last in the existing XML file as shown above.

Can anyone share some idea to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In the XML it is visible that

1. testing-results is the rootElement.
2. Inside that, the testing methods are child elements.

So, if you are adding **test-method** as child element, please append it to **testing-reults** element, instead of appending it to **test-method**. Also I think you are using test-method as a root element with this code you attached

```
NodeList rootElement = doc.getElementsByTagName("test-method");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
static String EXISTING =
        "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
        "<testng-results skipped=\"0\" failed=\"0\" total=\"10\"\n" +
        "    passed=\"10\">\n" +
        "    <test-method status=\"FAIL\" is-config=\"true\"\n" +
        "        duration-ms=\"4\" started-at=\"2018-08-16T21:43:38Z\"\n" +
        "        finished-at=\"2018-08-16T21:43:38Z\">\n" +
        "        <params>\n" +
        "            <param index=\"0\">\n" +
        "                <value>\n" +
        "          <![CDATA[org.testng.TestRunner@31c2affc]]>\n" +
        "                </value>\n" +
        "            </param>\n" +
        "        </params>\n" +
        "        <reporter-output>\n" +
        "        </reporter-output>\n" +
        "    </test-method> <!-- setParameter -->\n" +
        "\n" +
        "    <test-method status=\"FAIL\" is-config=\"true\"\n" +
        "        duration-ms=\"5\" started-at=\"2018-08-16T21:44:55Z\"\n" +
        "        finished-at=\"2018-08-16T21:44:55Z\">\n" +
        "        <reporter-output>\n" +
        "            <line>\n" +
        "         <![CDATA[runSettlement Value Set :false]]>\n" +
        "            </line>\n" +
        "        </reporter-output>\n" +
        "    </test-method> <!-- setSettlementFlag -->\n" +
        "\n" +
        "</testng-results>";

static String APPEND =
        "<test-method duration-ms=\"4\"  finished-at=\"2018-08-16T21:46:55Z\"  is-config=\"true\"  test-instance-name=\"DummyTestcase\" >\n" +
        "    <reporter-output>\n" +
        "        <line>\n" +
        "        </line>\n" +
        "    </reporter-output>\n" +
        "</test-method>";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();

    Document existingDoc = builder.parse(
            new ByteArrayInputStream(EXISTING.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
    Document appendDoc = builder.parse(
            new ByteArrayInputStream(APPEND.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));

    Node root = existingDoc.getDocumentElement();

    root.appendChild(existingDoc.importNode(appendDoc.getDocumentElement(), true));
    root.appendChild(existingDoc.createTextNode("\n"));
    print(existingDoc);
}

static void print(Document doc) throws Exception {
    TransformerFactory.newInstance()
        .newTransformer()
        .transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(System.out));
}
```

Comment: Let me try this.

Comment: I'm getting below error  [Fatal Error] :851:9: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
Exception in thread "main" org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 851; columnNumber: 9; XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.

Comment: Is it possible to done through XSLT. I just noticed your answer for my different question. You just solved it by using XSLT. Is there any way to follow the same to solve this. Your help really really very appreciated